# Run a data collection script for virtual containers on a parent server

Tags: php, mysql, awk, cron, monitoring

I am currently attempting to build a NOC interface.

Ideally, I want to be able to run a script via cron to collect available disc space on every vm contained on the parent server. I want to then get this displayed neatly on a tv screen.

So far, I have a for loop that can show available disk space:

```
for i in `df -h | awk '{print $4}'`; do echo $i; done;
```

I am looking for insight on getting the data into a PHP file or injected into a mysql array.

Any ideas or guidance would be so awesome!

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: My first thought is to run a PHP script with cron that executes the awk command and gather the data that way.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for i in `df -h | awk '{print $4}'`; do echo $i; done;
```

is just the same as:

```
df -h | awk '{print $4}'
```